# ASPxCombobox, Allow user input and dropdown selection

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net, devexpress

I'm using devexpress ASPxComboBox, however I wanted to know how I can allow the user to enter values(in case it is not in the list) or choose from a dropdown list.

An example would be great!

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 2):

I have written a code which allows you to add a new Item to the ComboBox's Items collection if the Enter key is pressed.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function findItemByText(editor, newText) {
        for(var i = 0; i< editor.GetItemCount(); i++)
            if(editor.GetItem(i).text == newText)
                return true;
        return false;
    }   

    function tryAddNewItem(editor, newText) {
        if(!findItemByText(editor, newText))
            editor.AddItem(newText);
    }
   </script>
```

...

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox1" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDown" ValueType="System.String"
            Width="286px">
            <Items>
                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Item 0" Value="0" />
                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Item 1" Value="1" />
            </Items>
            <ClientSideEvents KeyPress="function(s,e) {
                if(e.htmlEvent.keyCode == 13) 
                    tryAddNewItem(s, s.GetText());
            }"/>
```

Comment: Note that `DropDownStyle="DropDown"` rather than `DropDownStyle="DropDownList"`, which allows a new value to be typed.